# Mediawiki: oojs-ui.styles.icons module causes 500 server error

Tags: php, mediawiki, visual-editor

I installed VisualEditor for Mediawiki and configured it correctly, so that the editing mode worked fine. But after upgrading to a newer Mediawiki version, VisualEditor doesn't work anymore.

Once I checked my DOM console I noticed, that the issue is caused by a module called oojs-ui.styles.icons creating a 500 server error. I also took a look into my error.log file. These are the essential details:

```
2016/01/31 03:33:47 [error] 1178#0: *50446 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity &quot;/var/www/html/Wiki/resources/lib/oojs-ui/themes/mediawiki/images/icons/add.svg&quot; in /var/www/html/Wiki/includes/resourceloader/ResourceLoaderImage.php on line 275
PHP message: PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/Wiki/includes/resourceloader/ResourceLoaderImage.php on line 278
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function appendChild() on a non-object in /var/www/html/Wiki/includes/resourceloader/ResourceLoaderImage.php on line 281" while reading response header from upstream, client: 123.123.123.123, server: domain.com, request: "GET /load.php?debug=true&modules=oojs-ui.styles.icons&* HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "domain.com"
```

Obviously the filepath can't be recognized, because of the `&quot;` attribute. So I checked line 275 of the file /var/www/html/Wiki/includes/resourceloader/ResourceLoaderImage.php, which contains the following:

```
protected function variantize( $variantConf, ResourceLoaderContext $context ) {
    $dom = new DomDocument;
    $dom->load( $this->getPath( $context ) ); ########## Line 275
    $root = $dom->documentElement;
    $wrapper = $dom->createElement( 'g' );
    while ( $root->firstChild ) {
        $wrapper->appendChild( $root->firstChild );
    }
    $root->appendChild( $wrapper );
    $wrapper->setAttribute( 'fill', $variantConf['color'] );
    return $dom->saveXml();
}
```

Normally, the php function `getPath()` should work fine, shouldn't it? I am  wondering why this is not working. I updated every extension afterwards but still no changes.

What do I have to do, in order to fix the error message from the error.log file?

Comment: The error segment `failed to load external entity` is the important thing here. THe call to `getPath()` may have succeeded, but the surrounding `load()` call is not able to retrieve the address returned by `getPath()` and the code does not handle the possibility that `$dom` is not a successfully loaded DOMDocument.

Comment: So what would you recommend me to do? I was contempalting, that the bug is issued by the LocalSettings.php. I am also wondering why this is works with Wikipedia, meanwhile they have the same mediawiki version, (and probably the same VE release as well)

Comment: I would probably try to debug the returned value from `getPath()` by inserting something like `var_dump($this->getPath()); die();` before the `load()` call to at least understand what DOMDocument is attempting to retrieve.

Comment: Ok I ran the code instead of the one in line 275. The output of your code was: string(78) "/var/www/html/Wiki/resources/lib/oojs-ui/themes/mediawiki/images/icons/add.svg"

So there seems to be the additional text `string(78)` in the variable `$context`. Guess this needs to be formated first..?

Comment: The `string(78)` is part of the var_dump() debug output --  it's the character length of the string `/var/www/html/Wiki/resources/lib/oojs-ui/themes/mediawiki/images/icons/add.svg`  The call to `load()` is failing on that string. Does that path exist on your filesystem? Is the file readable?

Comment: Yes the vector image is in the called directory. I applied the correct permissions (recursively) of the icons folder before.

Comment: I don't think it's that svg causing the failure, because that is not an "external" resource. The `die()` for debugging may be halting execution on a previous call to this method.  If you remove the `die()`, you may get debug output for every call to the method, and at the final one before the error should be the true path failing on `load()`.

Comment: Yeah sure, but for most of the people the code works as it is, since this is available in the official mediawiki release. And you forget that the code shows the `"` marks as a html markup, which probably is the real problem.  Well...